# How to connect to mysql server from nodejs app using sequelize. But, earlier i used docker and ran a mysql container. Now am unable to connect locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express, sequelize.js

Whenever i try to connect my express.js app to the node server. I get an error(see below console message).
Earlier, before dockerizing my app everything used to run smoothly but after creating my mysql-image-container(docker) and running mysql through docker everything went well. But now, when i try to connect my app with SQL server and not through the docker-container i get the following error

```
(node:22136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:94:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:220:24)      
at async C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:174:32
at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:197:7)  
at async C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:304:26
at async MySQLQueryInterface.tableExists (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:102:17)    
at async Function.sync (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:939:21)
at async Sequelize.sync (C:\Users\A\ARISE1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:376:9)
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:22136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22136) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have tried deleting docker file, mysql-image-container(from docker) but am still unable to connect my app with local mysql server. And now if i even try to connect to my database through SQL-command line, i am unable to do so, even with correct credentials. Though I'm able to connect to the database through MySQL Workbench.
The docker command used to build-image/run the container is:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name nodejs-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=database -d mysql:5.7
```

before this, i used to right-click on the dockerfile and choose build image option.
I didn't completely understood the contents of Dockerfile and so i mixed some code from online sources.

Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Hi, can you post your docker commands used to run the containers.  The default docker network doesn't permit access to the host so that might be why you are running into problems.

Comment: How are you launching the application container?  How do you configure the database location in the application?

Comment: I'm launching the application container by using docker desktop or by docker extension in my VSCode. And for configuring the database location i use

const sequelize = new Sequelize("root", "pass", "arise", {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql"
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize( username, password, database, {
    host: host,
    dialect: dialect
});
```

Instead of above, it should be this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(  database, username, password, {
        host: host,
        dialect: dialect
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code.
Also see the the code below on how you establish a connection

```
const { Sequelize,DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const config={
    HOST:"localhost",// you can replace this with the url of where your server is hosted or an ip adress
    USER:"root",
    PASSWORD:"yourpassword",
    DB:"yourDb",
    dialect:"mysql",//sqlite, mariadb
    pool:{
        max:5,
        min:0,
        acquire:30000,
        idle:10000
    }

const sequelize= new Sequelize(
config.DB,
config.USER,
config.PASSWORD,
{

    host:config.HOST,
    dialect:config.dialect,
    operatorAliases:false,
    pool:{
        max:config.pool.max,
        min:config.pool.min,
        acquire:config.pool.acquire,
        idle:config.pool.idle
    }
}

)
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```